# Заголовочные файлы при использовании шаблонных классов C++ с компилятором CLang

Tags: c++, macos, шаблоны-с++, gcc, clang

Написал template класс, который в качестве примера выводит sizeof от типа подставляемого шаблона.

**BaseInformer.h**

```
template<typename ValueType>
class BaseInformer {
  private:
    int size;
  public:
    BaseInformer();
    virtual ~BaseInformer(){}
  public:
    virtual void printInfo();
    void printValue(ValueType value);
  public:
    std::string getSize() const;
    virtual std::string getName() const = 0;
};

extern template class BaseInformer<int>;
extern template class BaseInformer<char>;
```

**BaseInformer.cpp**

```
template class BaseInformer<int>;
template class BaseInformer<char>;

template<typename ReturnValue>
BaseInformer<ReturnValue>::BaseInformer() {
    size=sizeof(ReturnValue);
}

template<typename ValueType>
void BaseInformer<ValueType>::printValue(ValueType value) {
    std::cout << getName() << " " << value << "\n";
}

template<typename ValueType>
void BaseInformer<ValueType>::printInfo() {
    std::cout << getName() << " " << getSize() << "\n";
}

template<typename ValueType>
std::string BaseInformer<ValueType>::getSize() const {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << size;
    return ss.str();
}
```

От него унаследованы классы IntInformer и CharInformer, имеют почти одинаковое содержание:

**IntInformer.h**

```
class IntInformer : public BaseInformer<int> {
  public:
    IntInformer(){}
    virtual ~IntInformer() override {}
  public:
    virtual std::string getName() const override;
};
```

**IntInformer.cpp**

```
std::string IntInformer::getName() const {
    return "Int";
}
```

Соответственно, ниже сегмент функции main

**main.cpp**

```
int main() {
    ...
    std::cout << "template printInfo()\n";
    IntInformer().printInfo();
    CharInformer().printInfo();
    ...
}
```

Код выше успешно компилируется и исполняется при использовании [MinGW64](http://mingw-w64.org), так же успешно собирает компилятор [MSVC2019x64](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/). Однако, при попытке собрать с использованием CLang на macOS, выходит следующий лог:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "BaseInformer<char>::printValue(char)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "BaseInformer<char>::printInfo()", referenced from:
      vtable for BaseInformer<char> in baseinformer.o
      vtable for CharInformer in charinformer.o
      _main in main.o
  "BaseInformer<char>::BaseInformer()", referenced from:
      CharInformer::CharInformer() in main.o
  "BaseInformer<int>::printValue(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "BaseInformer<int>::printInfo()", referenced from:
      vtable for BaseInformer<int> in baseinformer.o
      vtable for IntInformer in intinformer.o
      _main in main.o
  "BaseInformer<int>::BaseInformer()", referenced from:
      IntInformer::IntInformer() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [cpp-template-header] Error 1
20:02:57: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
```

Скажите пожалуйста, а какой правильный вариант применения синтаксиса шаблонов, если желательна сборка без привязки к множеству поддерживаемых компиляторов (запустить это дело под CLang)? По возможности, хотелось бы сохранить разделение на заголовочные и файлы исходного кода. Для удобства, разместил проект [тут](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/cpp-template-header).

Comment: @Abyx https://pastebin.com/zZGgm2EU

Comment: Я думаю следует закрыть дубликатом с вопросом о том, где определение шаблонных методов, выносят в `cpp` файлы, а потом жалуются на `Undefined Reference`.

Comment: @ヒミコ: С чего бы это вдруг? В данном случае очевидно, что автор прекрасно понимает проблему, по каковой причине он и выполняет **явное инстанцирование**. Это вопрос про явное инстанцирование.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Определение явного инстанцирования шаблона должно следовать *за* определением самого шаблона.

Определение явного инстанцирования шаблона класса является одновременно определением явного инстанцирования шаблонов всех его членов. Поэтому обычно определение явного инстанцирования класса должно указываться *после* определений шаблонов его членов.

Если какие-то члены шаблонного класса не определены к моменту появления определения явного инстанцирования всего класса, то они *не будут* явно инстанцированы. См. http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#12

> An explicit instantiation definition that names a class template specialization explicitly instantiates the class template specialization and is an explicit instantiation definition of **only those members that have been defined at the point of instantiation**.

Именно это и произошло в вашем случае: ни один из ваших методов класса явно инстанцирован не был. Поэтому линкер их не нашел.

Переместите строчки

```
template class BaseInformer<int>;
template class BaseInformer<char>;
```

в самый низ файла `BaseInformer.cpp`